# How to get composer.phar version from inside PHP itself?

Tags: php, composer-php, version

is there any way to know which `composer`(`.phar`) version **had generated** the currently loaded autoloader?

Meaning, after running:

```
composer init
composer update
```

And creating a php file that includes the autoloader:

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// ??
```

Inside this php file, Can i somehow determine which version of composer was used to generated the `vendor` folder (hence also the `autoload.php` file)?

Is there something **in php**, under the `\Composer` namespace or whatever, that tells me that (for example) a composer v`2.5.5` generated the autoloader?

Running `shell_exec('composer --version')` is not a solution because

1. the `composer` binary that was used, might not be whatever the shell locates when running `composer --version`
2. php's shell functions (`proc_open`, `shell_exec`, `exec`, etc) might be disabled for security reasons

I also found `\Composer\InstalledVersions::getAllRawData()`, `\Composer\InstalledVersions::getRootPackage()` and similar, but there is no information about composer itself.

Also, final note: requiring `composer/composer` in my `composer.json` and then analyzing that package, is *not* the same thing...

thank you

Comment: No, you can't determine that. I'm not sure what value you think that might have. You _can_ find `plugin-api-version` in your `composer.lock` file however. Not quite the same thing, but likely more appropriate to what you're trying to do.

Comment: What _are_ you trying to do? It's more than a bit strange to want to know this. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Sammitch i would have guessed that someone would bring up the XYP ahah :) --- it started because i wanted to determine the version of the composer running in GCP App Engine, because it seems to be out of date and partially incompatible with Laravel (generates warnings during `composer install`) --- so i wanted to find out the version in use in GCP to be sure

Comment: the problem with GCP is that the FS is ephemeral so i can't seem to be able to log to files during installation

Comment: Why are you trying to run Composer inside AppEngine at all? You should be running Composer commands locally and pushing the resulting directory structure to GAE. If you're making GAE run `composer install/update/etc` every time a request comes in you're wasting a lot of time/money on that.

Comment: "incompatible with Laravel" - I doubt that this is the case. If you are facing any **real** problem with that, why not add it to the question by editing it?

Comment: @NicoHaase because, **by far**, everything _seems_ to work **notwithstanding** those warnings. But a possible Laravel update in the (near?) future might break smt, and in that case i'd want to know as much as i can about the problem, to immediately report it to both the Laravel and GCP teams. *As of today*, this has become more of a **challenge**, that's why i did not reference Laravel in the question: it's not that relevant to me, right now. Even though.... [someone already had problems with it just 2 months ago](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/x/m-p/531450)

Comment: There is no need to have Composer even installed on any system running your application. If you fear any problem with an updated version of Laravel, use a CI pipeline that runs unit or integration tests on your application before merging any updates

Comment: i don't understand why both you @sammitch and @nicohaase say that there is no need for composer or that i shouldn't run composer on GCP. have you seen both [#1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/building-app#composer) and [#2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/specifying-dependencies) ? maybe @sammitch it isn't clear: the `composer.lock` is actually generated on my pc, then deployed to GAE, then GAE runs `composer install`, but the outcome depends on both the version of the php binary running the `composer.phar` command, and the composer version

Comment: If you generate the `composer.lock` on your local PC and deploy it, `composer install` does the same regardless of the Composer version you are using. If that is not the case and you observe something different, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: The point is that composer generates all the files necessary during `composer install` after which composer is _completely unnecessary_. You can and _should_ run composer locally, so long as you ship the app's directory, _`/vendor` and all_, to GAE. Further to that, `composer install` is a very expensive and time-consuming operation that you absolutely do not want running every time GAE fires up your app.

Comment: @Sammitch uploading the entire `vendor` folder it's very impractical to me, because i don't have a good internet connection. i was just following Google's own guides, linked in my previous comment. i did not see any reference to what you described. so let me understand: i should add to `.gcloudignore` both `composer.json` and `composer.lock` in order **not** to upload them and not to trigger composer on GAE, and (i don't know how), i should also **re**-include the `vendor` folder in `.gcloudignore` (as it was ignored by `.gitignore` which is in turn included in `.gcloudignore`). correct?

Comment: Both composer.json and composer.lock should be present on a deployed app. For example, Symfony needs to access them to read the proper application root

Comment: ok final question about these laravel thingies: **so, i should push everything to GAE, `/vendor`, `composer.json` and `composer.json`?** it will still trigger an `composer install`..  ------  and no, @NicoHaase, `composer install` with an already generated `composer.lock` does not do the _exact_ same "regardless of the composer version you are using". try using an ancient composer, like the 1.1 version discussed in the GCP community post i linked before, everything breaks, because of the incompatibility between composer and newer php versions (i'm using 8.2 both locally and on GCP).

Comment: laravel aside, **as i said above**, the question is more of a challenge/curiosity at this point, about whether or not it's possible to detect the composer version in a composer project, via php or something else. anyway i just found a possible solution, i'll post it below

Comment: "everything breaks" - okay, if you use an horribly outdated version of Composer, that might be the case

Comment: @NicoHaase well it's not a matter of "if **you use** an horribly outdated version of composer", if you have no control over the environment. the guy in that linked thread said that his GAE environment was running composer 1.1 (released 2016). the thread is dated march 2023. i started using GAE 1 month later, so i guess they updated GCP's composer to something _newer_ (but not the newest, as i had deprecation warnings and whatnot). still, enough with GAE, it was not the point of the question. i added an answer below, if you want to comment on it, there's _another_ reference to GCP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using composer's scripts, and possibly a support file.

`composer.json`:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "pre-install-cmd": [
            "@composer --version"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "@composer --version"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "@composer --version >composer_version.log"
        ]
    }
}
```

[From the composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#calling-composer-commands):

> To call Composer commands, you can use @composer which will automatically resolve to whatever composer.phar is currently being used

Redirecting to a file ***might*** be a way to have some information in environments where you don't have access to the entire `composer install` log, like GAE on GCP, for example; the problem with this particular case is that the file system is either ephemeral or read only, so who knows where the `composer_version.log` file ends up, if it even gets created... but that's a different question.

---

EDIT:
Redirecting to a file allows for reading that file with php via a simple `file_get_contents()`, which was the original question.

So, to recap:
`composer.json`

```json
{
  "scripts":{
    "post-install-cmd": ["@composer --version >composer_version.log"]
  }
}
```

and some `file.php`:

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // not even necessary actually

$composerVersion = file_get_contents('composer_version.log');
echo $composerVersion;
```

That's it.